# How to calculate averages from a column, each of these averages referring to a 24 row interval?

Tags: excel, macos, sqlite

enter code hereI have a very extensive table of hourly concentrations of particulate matter emissions, from which i have to calculate daily averages.

In excel, I have used a compound function of  `OFFSET`, `ROW` and `AVG`, which worked perfectly, but I couldn't figure out how to execute this same task in sqlite.

**The following was what I used in excel:**

`=AVERAGE(OFFSET(cell reference; number of offset rows; number of offset columns; range in rows; range in columns))`

1. With a fixed cell reference (column label):

`=AVERAGE(OFFSET($E$1;`

2. Using `ROW()`, which returns the number/position of the row in the
   table, and multiplied by 24, to have an offset of a multiple of 24 -
   as I had 24 hourly values per day. This allowed me to calculate only
   once and drag the function down, as the offset was increased in
   every    row in the result column, and '24' was multiplied by 1 then
   2, 3, 4      and so on;

`1+(ROW(A1)*24);`

3. No offset in columns:

`0;`

4. 24 row range (aiming to calculate daily averages from hourly
   values):

`24;`

5. Finally, 1 as column range

`1)).`

`=AVERAGE(OFFSET($E$1;1+(ROW(A1)*24);0;24;1))`

Here is a small section from my database:

```
CREATE TABLE daily_emission_averages (
    date_hourly TEXT,
    time TEXT,
    PM10_hourly INTEGER);
INSERT INTO daily_emission_averages (date_hourly, time, PM10_hourly)
    VALUES (1/1/2016, 1:00, 28),
    VALUES (1/1/2016, 2:00, 31),
    VALUES (1/1/2016, 3:00, 28),
    VALUES (1/1/2016, 4:00, 21),
    VALUES (1/2/2016, 1:00, 12),
    VALUES (1/2/2016, 2:00, 13),
    VALUES (1/2/2016, 3:00, 23),
    VALUES (1/2/2016, 4:00, 25),
    VALUES (1/3/2016, 1:00, 2),
    VALUES (1/3/2016, 2:00, 9),
    VALUES (1/3/2016, 3:00, 7),
    VALUES (1/3/2016, 4:00, 7);
```

To shorten the code, I included only four daily values. So calculating 4-hour averages instead of daily averages.

Comment: You want to do the same thing your excel formula does in Sqlite?

Comment: Exactly. I don't know if there are similar clauses/commands for this.

Comment: Does your table have a datetime column? It would be easy to do a GROUP BY statement if so. Otherwise you'll probably need to insert one first.

Comment: Please provide some sample data (as `create table` and `insert` statements for easy importing into a test db) and the expected results of that sample.

Comment: **not** as an image. How are we supposed to copy and paste that?

Comment: don't worry Shawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want daily averages then you could use :-

```
SELECT date_hourly,avg(pm10_hourly) FROM daily_emission_averages GROUP BY date_hourly;
```

Rather than assuming 24 rows per day it **GROUP**'s the rows according to the date. That is all rows that have the same date will be treated as a single row, when grouping [aggregate functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html), such as **avg** can be used.

Using your SQL (corrected) the the result of using the suggested query is :-

[image]

## Note!

Although grouping by **date_hourly** will work as every date is unique, using a date in Month/Day/Year format is cumbersome and not recommended

For example if you wanted the resulted sorted according to date using ORDER BY date_hourly would result in (if data for dates 1/10/2016, 1/12/2016 and 1/13/2016 were added) :-

[image]

- i.e. 1/2/2016 is considered to be after 1/10/2016

A solution could be to use an awkward/complex ORDER BY clause e.g.

```
ORDER BY 
    (substr(date_hourly,length(date_hourly) -3,4) * 10000)
    +  (substr(date_hourly,1,instr(date_hourly,'/')-1) * 100)
    + substr(date_hourly,instr(date_hourly,'/')+1, instr(substr(date_hourly,instr(date_hourly,'/')+1),'/')-1)
```

The better solution would be to use a **recognised date** format *(see Time Strings in the link below)** when storing the data e.g. DD-MM-YYYY, then not only can the data be easily grouped it can be easily sorted and also easily extracted and manipulated via the [Date/Time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)